# What effects does restarting sshd have on existing ssh sessions?

Tags: ssh, session

I've made some changes to the sshd_config. As I understand it, now I need to restart the sshd service.

What happens to existing ssh sessions for the users? Any pointers to documentation I need to read?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Existing sessions will remain active, using the pre-restart config. All new sessions will use the new config.

Answer (score 1):

when you do a configuration change, is better if you use reload function, if the agent provide or kill -HUP pid